# Timer Class - Can't find variable

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

I'm new to JavaScript and object-oriented programming. I'm trying to create a Timer object (I assume this is an object?).

My object is not working, I get the following error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: countdownTime" (over and over again).

My object is supposed to create a countdown timer. The user has the ability to set the amount of countdown time (in seconds) from which the timer counts down (property of my object). The user can also start and stop my timer (methods). The timer automatically stops at 0 but can be stopped early by the user (example: User looses all lives and there is still time remaining - timer should end).

Why isn't this working as expected?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkWTS/

Code:

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
// Timer object
var Timer = function() {

    // PROPERTIES
    this.countdownTime = 120; // amount of time the timer counts down from in seconds

    // METHODS
    // Start timer - starts the countdown timer
    this.Start = function() {
        var timer = setInterval(timerCall, 1000);
    };

    // End timer
    // timer automatically ends when countdown time reaches 0 BUT can be ended early 
    // Example: User looses all lives and there is still time remaining - timer should end
    this.End = function() {
        // Stop timer
        clearInterval(timer);
    };

    function timerCall() {          
        if (countdownTime > 0) {
            // Display time in output div
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = countdownTime;

            countdownTime--;    
        } else {
            // Stop timer
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

};

// Create new timer object
var myTimer = new Timer();

// Countdown from 30
myTimer.countdownTime = 30;

// Start the countdown
myTimer.Start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't see your variable because you should reference it like

`this.countdownTime = ...`

Do the following in your class:

`var self = this;`

Then in the `timerCall` function you do

`self.countdownTime = ...`

That should fix the countdown issue :)